# Navigating to Dynamic CRM home page after authentication

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I need to navigate to dynamic CRM main page after external login authentication.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675404.aspx

I have successfully able to retrieve the loged user details but i dont know how to redirect to the main page from my external page. below is part of my code.

```
 // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
                organizationProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

                // Now make an SDK call with the organization service proxy.
                // Display information about the logged on user.
                Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)organizationProxy.Execute(
                    new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
                SystemUser systemUser = organizationProxy.Retrieve("systemuser", userid,
                    new ColumnSet(new string[] { "firstname", "lastname" })).ToEntity<SystemUser>();
                Response.Write("Logged on user is {0} {1}."+
                    systemUser.FirstName+" "+ systemUser.LastName);
                Response.Redirect("https://redrocksoftware.crm5.dynamics.com/default.aspx");
```

Response.Redirect navigate back to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is strange. Article you mentioned describes retrieving access to the CRM Web Services from client software. But browser authentication is absolutely different thing. If you want to be authenticated in browser, you should enter credentials in login window.
Some useful information you can find [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmpowerobjects/archive/2012/12/07/dynamics-crm-portal-authentication-methods.aspx#.UWZbWJNkPSc)